# How to increase the limit on the size of the uploaded file?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, aspnetboilerplate

I'm use [ABP Zero Core MVC](https://aspnetboilerplate.com/Templates) template (ASP.Net Core 2.x, MVC, jQuery) version 4.2.0. When I try to upload a file using the AJAX to controller, I get an [HTTP 404.13](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/configuration/system.webServer/security/requestFiltering/requestLimits/) error, which indicates that the maximum file size is exceeded. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53428815/3129992) and [here](https://github.com/aspnetboilerplate/aspnetboilerplate/issues/3657) I found solutions to similar problem and try it solved so ajust, but they either do not fit the pattern used, or I'm doing something wrong.

How to increase the maximum upload file size in Zero Core?

```
// *.Web.Host\Startup\Program.cs 
// *.Web.Mvc\Startup\Program.cs
public static IWebHostBuilder CreateWebHostBuilder(string[] args) {
    return WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
        .UseKestrel(options => { 
            // no effect...  I can only small files uploaded
            options.Limits.MaxRequestBodySize = 1024 * 1024 * 1024; 
        })
        .UseStartup<Startup>();
}
```

Comment: What other things have you tried so far?  You may need a combination of techniques as this is not a limit in one location.

Comment: @Kami I tried to use the code specified above in the Program.cs files in * .Web.Mvc and * .Web.Host projects.

Comment: Have you tried the settings at https://github.com/aspnet/Announcements/issues/267 ?

Comment: @Kami Global Config variant - no effect, RequestSizeLimit attribute variant - no effect, Middleware variant - I'm not found any file for this.

Comment: Did you do these independently or at the same time? Also, you may need to change the IIS configuration in addition to these settings.

Comment: @Kami I tried the proposed solutions separately. Since the project is ASP.Net Core, then I can not understand what does it have to do with IIS? It seems to be used Kestrel or am I wrong? The project is launched yet from VisualStudio.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/185415/discussion-between-xelanimed-and-kami).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried to decorate the controller `action` with `[RequestSizeLimit(YOUR_MAX_TOTAL_UPLOAD_SIZE)]` along with the changes in `Startup.cs`?

```
services.Configure<FormOptions>(opt =>
{
    opt.MultipartBodyLengthLimit = YOUR_MAX_TOTAL_UPLOAD_SIZE;
});
```

---

btw, if you are planning to host the app on IIS, you can add `web.config` file to your project and configure the `upload size` there, rather than configuring it on the IIS server.

EDIT: as [@XelaNimed](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3129992/xelanimed)'s comment, adding the `web.config` file along with editing the `startup.cs`, got the code working.

```
<configuration>
  <location path="." inheritInChildApplications="false">
   <system.webServer>
     <handlers>
       <add name="aspNetCore" path="*" verb="*" modules="AspNetCoreModule" resourceType="Unspecified" />
     </handlers>
     <aspNetCore processPath="%LAUNCHER_PATH%" arguments="%LAUNCHER_ARGS%" stdoutLogEnabled="false" stdoutLogFile=".\logs\stdout">
       <environmentVariables />
     </aspNetCore>
   </system.webServer>
 </location>
 <system.webServer>
   <security>
      <requestFiltering>
        <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="YOUR_BYTES" />
       </requestFiltering>
    </security>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Comment: I tried to decorate the method with an `RequestSizeLimit` attribute, but the error `Multipart body length limit 134217728 exceeded` still occurs. The solution with editing the `*.Web.Mvc/Startup/Startup.cs` file and editing `*.Web.Mvc/web.config` works. Edit please your code, as in the answer above, since it is not obvious which files and methods need to be edited.

Answer (score 1):

#### Exceeded Maximum File Size in web.config - How Can This Be Fixed?

I have encountered an issue with my `web.config` file on my web server (`E:\\WebServer\\DBBweb\\web.config`). I realized that the maximum file size limit was exceeded once again. Here are the steps I took to identify and solve the problem:

1. I found that the size of the `web.config` file was 251KB, which is larger than the permitted maximum file size of 250KB.
2. I opened the Registry Editor (Regedit) as an Administrator.
3. I navigated to the key: `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\\SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\InetStp`.
4. I added a subkey named 'Configuration'.
5. I added a DWORD value named `MaxWebConfigFileSizeInKB` and set its value to a number greater than 251KB.
6. I then navigated to the key: `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\\SOFTWARE\\Wow6432Node\\Microsoft\\InetStp`. This key is identical to the previous key but contains the `Wow6432Node` in the path.
7. I repeated steps 4 and 5 for this key.
8. I stopped and started the application pool.
9. Lastly, I restarted the server.

This procedure had to be done for both keys because the website is utilizing 32-bit compatibility.

Despite this the team and I continue to advise against adding client services in the `web.config`. We suggest using an `APIHANDLER` instead, which functions as an extension of the `web.config`.

Could anyone provide additional solutions or confirm whether this is the most efficient way to handle the issue of exceeding maximum file size in the `web.config`? Also, could anyone shed light on the benefits of using an `APIHANDLER` over adding client services directly in the `web.config`?

Thank you in advance for your assistance.

Comment: This answers a different question.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

**Startup.cs**

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
  //add to beginning of the method... 
  services.Configure<FormOptions>(x =>
  {
      x.ValueLengthLimit = int.MaxValue;
      x.MultipartBodyLengthLimit = int.MaxValue;
      x.MultipartHeadersLengthLimit = int.MaxValue;
  });


}
```

Comment: Thanks for you reply, but occurs same error: HTTP 404.13