# How to migrate ASP.NET Framework configurations to ASP.NET Core?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-core, .net-core

I'm migrating an ASP.NET Framework application hosted on IIS to ASP.NET Core hosted on Kestrel.

In ASP.NET Framework, I have a web.config with dozens of custom configurations/optimizations, like:

```xml
<httpRuntime executionTimeout="120" maxUrlLength="8192" maxQueryStringLength="8192" />
```

Problem is that I can't find how to configuration those settings, like `maxQueryStringLength` in ASP.NET Core with Kestrel.

For example, in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39049955/13058468), the user says that it is not available in ASP.NET Core and recommends to use IIS or NGINX.

How can I migrate my `web.config` settings without using a `web.config` file in ASP.NET Core? I would prefer to use the default `appsettings.json` file.

Answer (score 4):

You may use ASP.NET Core Kestrel limits to make the appropriate configs

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.server.kestrel.core.kestrelserverlimits?view=aspnetcore-3.1

It could be done via configs in Program.cs

```html
#elif Limits
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            CreateHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
        }

        public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
            Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
                .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
                {
                    #region snippet_Limits
                    webBuilder.ConfigureKestrel(serverOptions =>
                    {
                        serverOptions.Limits.MaxConcurrentConnections = 100;
                        serverOptions.Limits.MaxConcurrentUpgradedConnections = 100;
                        serverOptions.Limits.MaxRequestBodySize = 10 * 1024;
                        serverOptions.Limits.MinRequestBodyDataRate =
                            new MinDataRate(bytesPerSecond: 100, 
                                gracePeriod: TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));
                        serverOptions.Limits.MinResponseDataRate =
                            new MinDataRate(bytesPerSecond: 100, 
                                gracePeriod: TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));
                        serverOptions.Listen(IPAddress.Loopback, 5000);
                        serverOptions.Listen(IPAddress.Loopback, 5001, 
                            listenOptions =>
                            {
                                listenOptions.UseHttps("testCert.pfx", 
                                    "testPassword");
                            });
                        serverOptions.Limits.KeepAliveTimeout = 
                            TimeSpan.FromMinutes(2);
                        serverOptions.Limits.RequestHeadersTimeout = 
                            TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1);
                    })
                    #endregion
                    .UseStartup<Startup>();
                });
#elif Port0
```

Kestrel options can also be set using a configuration provider. For example, the File Configuration Provider ( https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/?view=aspnetcore-3.1#file-configuration-provider ) can load Kestrel configuration from an appsettings.json or appsettings.{Environment}.json file:

```html
{
  "Kestrel": {
    "Limits": {
      "MaxConcurrentConnections": 100,
      "MaxConcurrentUpgradedConnections": 100
    },
    "DisableStringReuse": true
  }
}
```

Also, if you need to manage these things via code you may try to handle it via middleware

```html
public class RequestFilterMiddleware
    {
        private readonly RequestDelegate _next;
        private const long _allowedRequestQueryStringMaxLength = 100;
        private const long _allowedUrlStringMaxLength = 100;
        public RequestFilterMiddleware(RequestDelegate next)
        {
            _next = next;
        }

        public async Task Invoke(HttpContext httpContext)
        {
            var queryStringLength = httpContext.Request.QueryString.Value?.Length;
            if (queryStringLength > _allowedRequestQueryStringMaxLength)
            {
                //throw exception or send some appropriate http status code
            }

            var urlRequestLength = httpContext.Request.GetDisplayUrl().Length;
            if (urlRequestLength > _allowedUrlStringMaxLength)
            {
                //throw exception or send some appropriate http status code
            }

            using (var TokenSource = System.Threading.CancellationTokenSource.CreateLinkedTokenSource(httpContext.RequestAborted))
            {
                httpContext.RequestAborted = TokenSource.Token;
                var DelayTask = Task.Delay(500, TokenSource.Token);
                var NextTask = _next.Invoke(httpContext);
                if (await Task.WhenAny(DelayTask, NextTask).ConfigureAwait(false) == DelayTask)
                {
                    //LogStuff for long running requests
                   
                }
                TokenSource.Cancel();
            }

            await _next(httpContext);
        }
    }
```

Unfortunately, the timeout option is not available in Kestrel at this moment, to get more information you may read this topic https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/10079

However, it's possible at least to log long running requests in production for later optimization purposes.

Comment: Thanks, that looks like what I need. However, I could not find in the property list any of the examples that I've mentioned in the question: maxQueryStringLength, maxUrlLength, and executionTimeout. So, it seems that there are another way to configure.